Automatic enable and disable interrupt in TM4C1233E6PZ or not?
I am using TM4C1233E6PZ controller and i am using 3 interrupts

uart isr
gpio isr
timer isr
I just want to know that these ISR automatically handle enable and disable global interrupt or not?
Actually i want that if any ISR is already triggered then no other ISR should triggered.

My ISR is :-
extern "C" void DEBUGUARTIntHandler(void)
{
    uint32_t ui32Status;
    // Get the interrrupt status. //
    ui32Status = UARTIntStatus(UART4_BASE, true);
    static int msglen=0,datacnt=0;

    char tmpudr;
    UARTIntClear(UART4_BASE, ui32Status);
    // Loop while there are characters in the receive FIFO. //
    while(UARTCharsAvail(DEBUG_UART_BASE))
    {
        tmpudr = UARTCharGetNonBlocking(UART4_BASE);

        UARTCharPutNonBlocking(UART4_BASE, tmpudr);
        // data handling
    }

}

void SysTickIntHandler(void)
{
    // static uint16_t ADC_RAW = 0;

    if(u32DelayCounter != 0U)
    {
        u32DelayCounter--;
    } 
}  

extern "C" void GPIODIntHandler(void)
{
    uint8_t inputPinSts = 0;
    uint32_t EXTI_Sts = GPIOIntStatus(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, true);


    GPIOIntClear(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, EXTI_Sts);


    if(EXTI_Sts)
    {
        EXTI_Sts = 0;
        inputPinSts = GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2)/GPIO_PIN_2;

        if(inputPinSts)
        {
           // GPIOPinWrite(LED_PORT_BASE, LED2_PIN, GPIO_HIGH);
           GPIOPinWrite(LED_PORT_BASE, LED2_PIN, LED2_PIN);

        }
        else
        {
            GPIOPinWrite(LED_PORT_BASE, LED2_PIN, GPIO_LOW);
           // GPIOPinWrite(LED_PORT_BASE, LED2_PIN, LED2_PIN);
        }
    }
}


I tried to read data sheets but did not get success
